# Can't restore raspberry OS from img created with dd command

Tags: raspbian, image

I need to restore my Raspberry with an img created with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/home/pi/networkdrive/my.img bs=1M
```

I used Win32DiskImager to create the SD but the raspberry doesn't work.
I tryed also to put img inside a USB and plug to rapsberry (which runs default raspbian) and after using the command: `sudo dd bs=4M if=raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb` but this doesn't work too. What to do?

Comment: the command you used sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/home/pi/networkdrive/my.img bs=1M does not back up both partitions. You still need the FAT partition to bot from.

Answer (score 3):

> sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/home/pi/networkdrive/my.img bs=1M

You didn't make an image of the whole card, only of one partition.

If you were using a noobs based install then all you copied was the noobs data partition, you didn't actually back up your system.......

If you were using a non-noobs based install then you did back up the main linux partition. You would need to create a suitable partition table on the target device, restore the image to partition 2 and set up a fat partition with the raspberry pi boot files on partition 1.

Comment: It would help the OP if you explained how to create the partitions and copy them to the new card.